# Get mysqli object from custom class

Tags: php, class, mysqli, statistics

I am trying to make a class that, when called, creates a mysqli object and returns it as the result of class.

Longer explanation: I am trying to somehow make every mysqli go through a class for statistics purposes. The statistics for every mysqli query would go to global variable and i can print it at the end of page for deveopment purposes.

So if i do something like this:

```
$m = new sql;
$user = "a";
if ($n = $m->prepare("SELECT id FROM users WHERE username=?")) {
    $n -> bind_param("s", $user);
    pre($n);
    $n -> execute();
    $n -> bind_result($id);

    while($n -> fetch()){
        print_r($id);
    }
    $n -> close();
}
$m -> close();
```

The global variable (for example $GLOBALS['mysqli']) would contain time the query took and prepared query. Like so:

```
$GLOBALS['mysqli'][1]['query'] = "SELECT id FROM users WHERE username=?";
$GLOBALS['mysqli'][1]['time'] = 20; //ms
```

**The problem:**
Even when i make a function for sql class called prepare($query) and return object with prepared statement called, next function bind_param returns error "Call to undefined method sql::prepare()". I assume it trie to call that function for sql class.

OKay, i cant explain it better but maybe i can show:

```
    class sql {
    /*
        $r = new sql;
        $GLOBALS['info']['mysqli'];
    */

    public
        $object,
        $query,

        $start,
        $end,
        $time,

        $stat,
        $error;


    public function __construct()  {
        $this->start = microtime(true);
        $this->error = null; 

        $this->object = new_m(); 

    } 
    public function __destruct()  {  
        $this->end = microtime(true);
        $this->stat['time'] = $this->end-$this->start;
        $GLOBALS['info']['mysqli'][] = $this->stat;

    } 

    public function prepare($q) {
        $this->stat['query'] = $q;
        $this->object->prepare($q);
        return $this->object;
    } 

}
function new_m() {
    $cserver = substr($_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'],strpos($_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'],"."),100);

    $local_server = s('mysqli_local_server');
    $local_user = s('mysqli_local_user');
    $local_pass = s('mysqli_local_pass');
    $local_db = s('mysqli_local_db');

    $server = s('mysqli_server');
    $user = s('mysqli_user');
    $pass = s('mysqli_pass');
    $db = s('mysqli_db');

    if ($cserver == $local_server) {
        return new mysqli('127.0.0.1',$local_user,$local_pass,$local_db); 
    }
    else {
        return new mysqli($server,$user,$pass,$db);
    }
}
```

I know this example has some logic errors but i think it shows what i am trying to do.

var_dump($this->object) just before returning it:

```
mysqli Object
```

(
    [affected_rows] => -1
    [client_info] => mysqlnd 5.0.10 - 20111026 - $Id: b0b3b15c693b7f6aeb3aa66b646fee339f175e39 $
    [client_version] => 50010
    [connect_errno] => 0
    [connect_error] => 
    [errno] => 0
    [error] => 
    [error_list] => Array
        (
        )

```
[field_count] => 1
[host_info] => 127.0.0.1 via TCP/IP
[info] => 
[insert_id] => 0
[server_info] => 5.5.27
[server_version] => 50527
[stat] => Uptime: 17706  Threads: 1  Questions: 329  Slow queries: 0  Opens: 55  Flush tables: 1  Open tables: 1  Queries per second avg: 0.018
[sqlstate] => 00000
[protocol_version] => 10
[thread_id] => 67
[warning_count] => 0
```

)

Comment: Can you `var_dump($this->object)` in your prepare function?

Comment: Done, i made the var_dump

Comment: Anyone? This is really vital for my project.